# Detect Android screen is not use by long time

Tags: android, screen

I want make app background running that check user is interaction with device.

It is any way to check user don't use device for long time. (Any app is working, but user don't touch screen).

Answer (score 0):

This method `onUserInteraction()` is invoked every time the user interacts with the screen, it's in your activity.

You can set last time it was invoked and check periodically and do something if certain amount of time has passed.

[Check it out](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction())

Comment: But it works in Activity. I want check screen is clicked when Service is running.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that, but what are you trying to accomplish, maybe there's a better way to do it.